# Thread.sleep() will prevent Java memory inconsistency when testing volatile

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I'm testing the `memory consistency` function of the `volatile` keyword.

This is code that does NOT use volatile, the program will be stuck as expected.

```
package cn.demojie.singleton;

public class VolatileTest2 {
  private static boolean flag = false;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new Thread(
            () -> {
              while (!flag) {
                /* Uncomment it, the program won't get stuck anymore
                try {
                  Thread.sleep(0);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
                */
              }
            })
        .start();

    Thread.sleep(50);
    flag = true;
  }
}
```

But when I add `Thread.sleep()` like the comments above, the program won't get stuck anymore.

It seems the memory consistency is in effect. Why?

`System.out.println()` also works as the `Thread.sleep()`